# how can I solve this JavaScript runtime error?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have got an old `ASP.NET` web page. When I press F5, Visual Studio is giving me error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'txtAppl' of undefined or null reference.

HTML page,

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>  

<script runat="server" src="uzpo2003_tbbuild.cs"></script>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title></title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="uzpo2003_client.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body onload="form_load();">  
</body>  
</html>
```

uzpo2003_client.js,

```js
function form_load() {  
    if (document.formSelect.txtAppl.value == -99999999)  
    return null;      
}
```

uzpo2003_tbbuild.cs,

```
public class TableBuild
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    public string tblBuilder(string department, string un)
    {
        int dept = int.Parse(department);

        string dom;
        dom = "<center><table border='0' style='font:14pt;'  bgcolor='#A7C7B7'>";
        dom += "<input type = 'text' name = 'txtAppl' value = '' size=16 id = 'Text1'></P>";
        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Apparently `document.formSelect` is undefined. You need to debug to find out why that is.

Comment: Look at the end of your `tblBuilder` function. What do you think is in the `output` variable when you call `ToString()`? Because it ain't what's in `dom`...

Comment: I think the error is at this line `if (document.formSelect.txtAppl.value == -99999999)` but as you don't have posted html, I assume formSelect is the id of the form, can you make sure it is spelled correctly?